# Structed logging for uWSGI HARAKIRI messages

Tags: python, logging, uwsgi

My observability/logging platform requires that logs be structured in a specific format in order for them to be ingested and available in the right place.

This involves JSON-structuring the logs with some metadata like which service it's coming from.

For normal uwsgi request logs I can solve it like this:

```xml
    <req-logger>app syslog:uwsgi-req</req-logger>
    <log-req-encoder>json {"service":"foo","message":"${msg}"}</log-req-encoder>
    <log-req-encoder>nl</log-req-encoder>
```

However, uWSGI has more than just request logs, there's also stuff I want to keep like Harakiri logs (when a worker has been processing longer than `HARAKIRI_TIMEOUT` seconds and gets killed):

```
HARAKIRI: -- syscall> running
HARAKIRI: -- wchan> 0
Tue Sep  5 10:10:39 2023 - HARAKIRI !!! worker 2 status !!!
Tue Sep  5 10:10:39 2023 - HARAKIRI [core 0] 10.52.241.81 - GET /foo/bar since 1693908338
Tue Sep  5 10:10:39 2023 - HARAKIRI !!! end of worker 2 status !!!
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 68) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 468)
DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 85) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 485)
```

These logs don't end up getting structured, so don't get ingested and get missed.

I tried setting a `log-encoder` to capture these like so:

```xml
    <logger>requests syslog:uwsgi-main</logger>
    <logformat>%(status) %(method) %(uri) | ip=%(var.HTTP_X_REAL_IP), dT=%(msecs)ms</logformat>
<log-encoder>json {"service":"foo","message":"${msg}"}</log-encoder>
    <log-encoder>nl</log-encoder>
```

but the problem is that this *also* includes the service logs, which themselves are *already* JSON-structured, so application logs end up double-wrapped and looking like this:

```
{"service":"foo","msg":"{\"service\":\"foo\",\"msg\":\"application log\"}"}
```

Ideally I'd like to apply the same `log-req-encoder` json structure to *every* log created by uWSGI so *nothing* is missed. Is there a good way to do this?